# ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | index=1 | ]] while exporting code from Selenium IDE to Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Exported Code:

```
 public void testUntitledTestCase() throws Exception {

    driver.get("URL");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='add-items']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("item_title")).sendKeys("Automation");

    driver.findElement(By.id("item_cat_id")).click();

    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | index=1 | ]]

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Cat1")).click();

    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | relative=parent | ]]

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='item-save']"").click();
  }
```

The error is at the point where Iframe opens up. The application has an form in which some fields has buttons - and on clicking those another view opens up in pop-up (Iframe). I need to select the element from the Iframe. It's throwing an error :

```
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | index=1 | ]].
// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | relative=parent | ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's a iFrame?

If It is try this to get iFrame "name". Will help you to focus on the right Iframe / window / tab.

Hope this will help you :)

> List ele = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
>           System.out.println("Number of frames in a page :" + ele.size());

for(WebElement el : ele){
          //Returns the Id of a frame.

```
        System.out.println("Frame Id :" + el.getAttribute("id"));
      //Returns the Name of a frame.

        System.out.println("Frame name :" + el.getAttribute("name"));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks JS Jamet! it Worked!

Comment: Cool ;) Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a frame but a pop-up or window try this:

> String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); // Store your parent window
>           String childWindowHandler = null;

```
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        childWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(childWindowHandler); // switch to popup window


    // perform operations on popup

    try {
        assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainDocumentContainer']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td")));
      } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
      }
      try {
        assertEquals("Numéro d'opération :   Epicure 1", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mainDocumentContainer']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")).getText());
      } catch (Error e) {
        verificationErrors.append(e.toString());


   //Back to main window   

    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
```